# How can I build my shared library (.so) so that symbols from a different shared library are also included?

Tags: gcc, c, ld

My shared library `libnew.so` uses some symbols form an already built third-party shared library `libold.so`. I would like to build an executable binary file that should be only linked against `libnew.so`. But **it still needs to be linked against `libold.so`** too. Otherwise, the linker complains about `undefined reference to symbol...` .

I used these commands to build `libnew.so` and the executable file. For some reason, it is only allowed to use the current directory and I cannot put my files somewhere else.

Btw, `nm libnew.so` shows symbols from `libold.so` as undefined. `ldd libnew.so` also does not report any `libold.so`. If I do not use `libold.so` for building `libnew.so`, the size of `libnew.so` will not be changed!

For libnew.so :

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -c libnew.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libnew.so.1 -o libnew.so.1.0 *.o -L. -lold
ln -sf libnew.so.1.0 libnew.so.1
ln -sf libnew.so.1.0 libnew.so
```

For the executable :

```
#this does not work and needs -lold as well.
gcc -Wall main.c -L. -lnew -o prog
```

Is there anything missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is missing is that your linker command

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libnew.so.1 -o libnew.so.1.0 *.o -L. -lold
```

does not *copy* objects from `libold.so`, but *refers* to symbols in that file to tell the dynamic loader where it can obtain those symbols.

Normally when someone is trying to suppress/hide a given library, they start by recombining the object-files which were used to make the shared library.  You *might* be able to accomplish this via *partial linking*, but I do not see a solution (since shared libraries and shared objects are not interchangeable).

Further reading:

- [Merge multiple .so shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915128/merge-multiple-so-shared-libraries) (says it will not work...)
- [What is Partial Linking in GNU Linker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391965/what-is-partial-linking-in-gnu-linker)
- [**`ld`** - The GNU linker](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld)